# Define text color of labels in TIKZ globally per tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I define a label color **for all labels** in a tikzpicture? The actual text color should remain black, only labels should have a different color.

Below is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,fit}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[level/.style={sibling distance=60mm/#1}]

\node [circle,draw] (z){$n$}
  child {node [rectangle,draw] (a) {$\frac{n}{2}$}
    child {node [circle,draw] (b) {$\frac{n}{2^2}$}
      child {node {$\vdots$}
        child {node [circle,draw] (d) {$\frac{n}{2^k}$}}
        child {node [circle,draw] (e) {$\frac{n}{2^k}$}}
      } 
      child {node {$\vdots$}}
    }
    child {node [circle,draw] (g) {$\frac{n}{2^2}$}
      child {node {$\vdots$}}
      child {node {$\vdots$}}
    }
  }
  child {node [circle,draw, label=$LABEL$] (j) {$\frac{n}{2}$}
    child {node [circle,draw] (k) {$\frac{n}{2^2}$}
      child {node {$\vdots$}}
      child {node {$\vdots$}}
    }
  child {node [circle,draw] (l) {$\frac{n}{2^2}$}
    child {node {$\vdots$}}
    child {node (c){$\vdots$}
      child {node [circle,draw] (o) {$\frac{n}{2^k}$}}
      child {node [circle,draw] (p) {$\frac{n}{2^k}$}
        child [grow=right] {node (q) {$=$} edge from parent[draw=none]
          child [grow=right] {node (q) {$O_{k = \lg n}(n)$} edge from parent[draw=none]
            child [grow=up] {node (r) {$\vdots$} edge from parent[draw=none]
              child [grow=up] {node (s) {$O_2(n)$} edge from parent[draw=none]
                child [grow=up] {node (t) {$O_1(n)$} edge from parent[draw=none]
                  child [grow=up] {node (u) {$O_0(n)$} edge from parent[draw=none]}
                }
              }
            }
            child [grow=down] {node (v) {$O(n \cdot \lg n)$}edge from parent[draw=none]}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

\node[draw,fill=black, fill opacity=.1, densely dotted,fit=(o) (p),inner sep=5pt,label=$LABEL$] {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image: Output MWE]

Comment: You can use `label={[blue]$LABEL$}` if you want blue labels (this is no incitation to drink whiskey :p), but this has to be done for every label you wish to color. Maybe there is an option to set that globally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can make use of the *every label* style, a style that only applies   to  all the *nodes* created with the *label* option.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,fit}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[level/.style={sibling distance=60mm/#1},
                    every label/.style={text=red}, % <------------
                    ]

\node [circle,draw] (z){$n$}
  child {node [rectangle,draw] (a) {$\frac{n}{2}$}
    child {node [circle,draw] (b) {$\frac{n}{2^2}$}
      child {node {$\vdots$}
        child {node [circle,draw] (d) {$\frac{n}{2^k}$}}
        child {node [circle,draw] (e) {$\frac{n}{2^k}$}}
      } 
      child {node {$\vdots$}}
    }
    child {node [circle,draw] (g) {$\frac{n}{2^2}$}
      child {node {$\vdots$}}
      child {node {$\vdots$}}
    }
  }
  child {node [circle,draw, label=$LABEL$] (j) {$\frac{n}{2}$}
    child {node [circle,draw] (k) {$\frac{n}{2^2}$}
      child {node {$\vdots$}}
      child {node {$\vdots$}}
    }
  child {node [circle,draw] (l) {$\frac{n}{2^2}$}
    child {node {$\vdots$}}
    child {node (c){$\vdots$}
      child {node [circle,draw] (o) {$\frac{n}{2^k}$}}
      child {node [circle,draw] (p) {$\frac{n}{2^k}$}
        child [grow=right] {node (q) {$=$} edge from parent[draw=none]
          child [grow=right] {node (q) {$O_{k = \lg n}(n)$} edge from parent[draw=none]
            child [grow=up] {node (r) {$\vdots$} edge from parent[draw=none]
              child [grow=up] {node (s) {$O_2(n)$} edge from parent[draw=none]
                child [grow=up] {node (t) {$O_1(n)$} edge from parent[draw=none]
                  child [grow=up] {node (u) {$O_0(n)$} edge from parent[draw=none]}
                }
              }
            }
            child [grow=down] {node (v) {$O(n \cdot \lg n)$}edge from parent[draw=none]}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

\node[draw,fill=black, fill opacity=.1, densely dotted,fit=(o) (p),inner sep=5pt,label=$LABEL$] {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]